# Is there a way to calculate the slope for each successive point in two data frames, store all the values for slope and then plot it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
v = df['Gate V']
i1 = df['Drain I.1']

     Drain V   Gate V       Drain I    
0       0.01    -5.00  3.270000e-14                
1       0.01    -4.85  1.740000e-14               
2       0.01    -4.70  2.620000e-14                
3       0.01    -4.55  6.270000e-14                
...     ...     ...    ...
```

I have a large .csv file that looks like the above except with a lot more data. My goal thus far has been to plot `Drain I` versus `Gate V` for several different `Drain V`. I've accomplished this by using the `v = ...` and `i1 = ...` statements as above, and then simply plotting `i1` vs `v`, `i2` vs `v`, and so on.

However, now I need to calculate the slope of every `Drain I` vs `Gate V` for every point and graph that as well. My initial thought was to use a `for` loop to calculate the slope for every entry in the `i1` (and `i2`, `i3`...) and/or v series, something like this:

```
for x in i1:
    slope1 = (i1[x+1] - i1[x]) / (v[x+1] - v[x])
```

I'd ideally then have the slope from point to point and could graph it using matplotlib. Obviously, that for loop will not work but I'm not sure how else to go about it.

Comment: Use `diff` and the ratio of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope as you calculate it in your loop is just the ratio of the successive diffs in the two columns:

```
deltas = df.diff().drop(0)
slope = deltas['Drain I'] / deltas['Gate V']
```

The `.drop(0)` will remove the first row of the diffs, which will be all NaNs to preserve the original shape.

Here is a small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gate V': [-5.00, -4.85, -4.70, -4.55], 'Drain V': [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01], 'Drain I': [3.270000e-14, 1.740000e-14, 2.620000e-14, 6.270000e-14]})
deltas = df.diff().drop(0)
slope = deltas['Drain I'] / deltas['Gate V']
```

You now have a `slope` Series containing

```
1   -1.020000e-13
2    5.866667e-14
3    2.433333e-13
dtype: float64
```

A basic plot can be obtained with `slope.plot()`:

[image]